# ASP.NET MVC Database ConnectionString Explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

In one of my ASP.NET MVC projects, the connectionString is given as follows in the `web.config` file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db_connection" 
    connectionString="Data Source=ASTRONOMY
    Initial Catalog=GALLERIA;
    user=sa_galleria;
    password=Tyrr#!!55u;
    providerName="" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This connection string is supposed to work on Microsoft SQL Server (Full Editions).

I found that this connection setting is a little different than what the MSDN article [here](http://[1]%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx) explains. Especially, the following differences exist:

1. Is the connectionStrings configuration case-insensitive?
2. What does `ASTRONOMY` refer to here? (as `Data Source`)
3. Can `User Id` be shortened as `user`?
4. What value is set for `providerName` if it's omitted or has an empty value?

Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 2):

1.Is the connectionStrings configuration case-insensitive?

*Some parts are, such as password*

2.What does ASTRONOMY refer to here? (as Data Source)

*That's the servername and instance eg `SERVER\SQLEXPRESS`*

3.Can User Id be shortened as user?

*Nope* ok, yes `UID` see comments

4.What value is set for providerName if it's omitted or has an empty value?

*NET Framework Data Provider* see [SQL providerName in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484771/sql-providername-in-web-config)

Have a look at

https://connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. For number 4, is there any article on MSDN? What is the default data provider if providerName is empty or omitted? Thanks.

Comment: You can shorten the User Id as UID

Comment: user=sa_galleria; I can't find any examples that actually use `user` instead of 'User Id' or 'UID'. Is `user` even a standard parameter or just a hidden trick?

Answer (score 0):

> Data Source=ASTRONOMY

*Data Source -or- Server -or- Address -or- Addr -or- Network Address*

The name or network address of the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. The port number can be specified after the server name: server=tcp:servername, portnumber. When specifying a local instance, always use (local). To force a protocol, add one of the following prefixes: np:(local), tcp:(local), lpc:(local)

ADO.NET 2.0 does not support asynchronous commands over shared memory for SQL Server 2000 or earlier. However, you can force the use of TCP instead of shared memory, either by prefixing tcp: to the server name in the connection string, or by using localhost.

---

> Initial Catalog=GALLERIA;

*Initial Catalog -or- Database*

The name of the database.

---

> user=sa_galleria;

The SQL Server login account.

---

> password=Tyrr#!!55u;

*Password -or- Pwd*

The password for the SQL Server account logging on. Not used with (the strongly recommended) 'Integrated Security=true' option. **Case sensitive**

---

> providerName=""

System.Data.SqlClient is the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server. ie .NET library for SQL Server.
In the web.config you should have the System.Data.SqlClient as the value of the providerName attribute. It is the .NET Framework Data Provider you are using.

---

Source: https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/